# How do I add multiple authenticated feeds to dependabot?

Tags: azure-devops, dependabot

I have a project that uses two authenticated nuget feeds in Azure DevOps and I'm trying to integrate Dependabot into it. As the feeds are in Azure DevOps naturally I need to authenticate them with an access token which I know how to do with a single feed but I'm getting JSON parser issues when using multiple feeds.

```
- task: dependabot@1
  displayName: 'Run Dependabot'
  inputs:
    packageManager: 'nuget'
    targetBranch: 'develop'
    versioningStrategy: 'auto'
    extraEnvironmentVariables: DEPENDABOT_EXTRA_CREDENTIALS=[{"type":"nuget_feed","token":"$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)","url":url1},
                                                            {"type":"nuget_feed","token":"$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)","url":url2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue, I didn't put quote marks around my URLs